# Is passing an argument the best solution for if/else decisions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, parameters, arguments

Using arguments/parameters to determine which path is taken through the if/else statement works for me, but I feel like there might be a better solution. Is there something that acts more like an ID that I could pass along instead of an argument/parameter? Maybe I'm over thinking this?

I have two separate functions, dog() and cat(), that each call a third function: mouse(). I am currently sending a unique argument via a shared parameter along with dog() and cat() to channel each function through different paths in an if/else statement inside the function mouse().

Here is my example which works as expected:

```js
cat();

function cat() {
  var solo = 1;
  var x = 50;
  mouse(solo, x);
}

dog();

function dog() {
  var solo = 2;
  var x = 25;
  mouse(solo, x);
}

function mouse(solo, x) {

  if (solo == 1) {
    console.log(x)
    console.log('cat')
  } else {
    console.log(x)
    console.log('dog')
  }
}
```

There is a secondary concern which is that I have many functions calling mouse(), and I don't want to have to define the variable `solo` for each of them. I'd prefer to have the functions that don't have `solo` defined simply utilize the `else` part of the conditional inside `function mouse()`. However, I'm worried this isn't good practice as it throws an `undefined` error.

For example, this throws an `undefined` error.

```js
mouse();

function mouse(solo, x) {

  if (solo == 1) {
    console.log(x)
    console.log('cat')
  } else {
    console.log(x)
    console.log('dog')
  }
}
```

Actual Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <script src="js/howler.core.js"></script>
  <script src="js/howler.spatial.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <script src="timeprobabilities.js"></script>

  <script>
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // MASTER START ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // initiates fist call to all clocks to each will start and can then be called again

    (function masterStart() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        A();
        TA();
      }, 0);
    }());

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // LOOPS SHARED OPTIONS ///////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var options = {
      numberOfSounds: 0,
      maxNumberOfSounds: 10
    };

    function logNumberOfSounds() { // passing options into this before is what broke code
      options.numberOfSounds++;
      //console.log('Number of sounds is: ' + options.numberOfSounds + '########');
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // LOOP A  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function A() {
      var optionsA = {
        // start time minimum and maximum
        startMinA: 0,
        startMaxA: 8000,
        playDurationMinA: 20000,
        playDurationMaxA: 20000,
        maxVolumeA: 1,
        //
        startMinB: 0,
        startMaxB: 30000,
        playDurationMinB: 20000,
        playDurationMaxB: 20000,
        maxVolumeB: 1,
        //
        startMinC: 0,
        startMaxC: 30000,
        playDurationMinC: 20000,
        playDurationMaxC: 20000,
        maxVolumeC: 1,
        //
        startMinD: 0,
        startMaxD: 30000,
        playDurationMinD: 20000,
        playDurationMaxD: 20000,
        maxVolumeD: 1,
        //
        startMinE: 0,
        startMaxE: 30000,
        playDurationMinE: 20000,
        playDurationMaxE: 20000,
        maxVolumeE: 1,
        //
        startMinF: 0,
        startMaxF: 30000,
        playDurationMinF: 20000,
        playDurationMaxF: 20000,
        maxVolumeF: 1,
        //
        startMinG: 0,
        startMaxG: 30000,
        playDurationMinG: 20000,
        playDurationMaxG: 20000,
        maxVolumeG: 1,
        //
        startMinH: 0,
        startMaxH: 30000,
        playDurationMinH: 20000,
        playDurationMaxH: 20000,
        maxVolumeH: 1,
        //
        startMinI: 0,
        startMaxI: 30000,
        playDurationMinI: 20000,
        playDurationMaxI: 20000,
        maxVolumeI: 1,
        //
        startMinJ: 0,
        startMaxJ: 30000,
        playDurationMinJ: 20000,
        playDurationMaxJ: 20000,
        maxVolumeJ: 1,
        //
        startMinK: 0,
        startMaxK: 30000,
        playDurationMinK: 20000,
        playDurationMaxK: 20000
      };

      localClock();

      function localClock() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          soundA(options, optionsA);
        }, 10); // these need to be called with delay so they don't use the other functions' paramaters
      }

      function soundA() {

        soundTA(1, 1); // Use something like this to call soundTA() so that the if/else statement will skip soundTA()

        var soundFileName = 'audio/60.wav';
        var fadeIn = 8000;
        var fadeOut = 8000;

        // calculates startDelay
        (function() {
          if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointA) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinA, optionsA.startMaxA);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointB) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinB, optionsA.startMaxB);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointC) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinC, optionsA.startMaxC);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointD) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinD, optionsA.startMaxD);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointE) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinE, optionsA.startMaxE);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointF) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinF, optionsA.startMaxF);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointG) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinG, optionsA.startMaxG);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointH) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinH, optionsA.startMaxH);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointI) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinI, optionsA.startMaxI);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointJ) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinJ, optionsA.startMaxJ);
          } else {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinK, optionsA.startMaxK);
          }
          masterStart(startDelay);
        })();

        function calculateStartDelay(startMin, startMax) {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * startMax) + startMin;
        }

        function calculatePlayDuration(playDurationMin, playDurationMax) {
          return Math.floor((Math.random() * playDurationMax) + playDurationMin);
        }

        function masterStart(startDelay) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointA) {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeA;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinA, optionsA.playDurationMaxA);
              localClock();
            } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointB) {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeB;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinB, optionsA.playDurationMaxB);
              localClock();
            } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointC) {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeC;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinC, optionsA.playDurationMaxC);
              localClock();
            } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointD) {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeD;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinD, optionsA.playDurationMaxD);
              localClock();
            } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointE) {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeE;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinE, optionsA.playDurationMaxE);
              localClock();
            } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointF) {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeF;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinF, optionsA.playDurationMaxF);
              localClock();
            } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointG) {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeG;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinG, optionsA.playDurationMaxG);
              localClock();
            } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointH) {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeH;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinH, optionsA.playDurationMaxH);
              localClock();
            } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointI) {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeI;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinI, optionsA.playDurationMaxI);
              localClock();
            } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointJ) {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeJ;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinJ, optionsA.playDurationMaxJ);
              localClock();
            } else {
              var maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeK;
              var playDuration = calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMinK, optionsA.playDurationMaxK);
            }
            loop(options, playDuration, soundFileName, maxVolume, fadeIn, fadeOut);
            console.log('A: ////////////////////////////////// ');
          }, startDelay);
        }
      }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // SHARED LOOP  ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function loop(options, playDuration, soundFileName, maxVolume, fadeIn, fadeOut) {

      //console.log('LOOP: soundFileName: ' + soundFileName);
      //console.log('LOOP: playDuration: ' + playDuration);
      //console.log('LOOP: maxVolume: ' + maxVolume);

      if (options.numberOfSounds < options.maxNumberOfSounds) { //Don't create more than the max number of sounds.

        var sound = getSound(soundFileName);
        var id2 = sound.play();


        logNumberOfSounds();

        sound.volume(0);
        sound.fade(0, maxVolume, fadeIn, id2); // FADE IN

        setTimeout(function() {

          sound.fade(maxVolume, 0, fadeOut, id2); // FADE OUT
          options.numberOfSounds--;

          // Attempt to clean up the sound object
          setTimeout(function() {
            sound.stop();
            sound.unload();
          }, fadeOut + 1000);
        }, playDuration);
      }

    }

    // PLAYER FOR MAIN SOUND FUNCTION /////////////////////////////
    function getSound(soundFileName) {
      return new Howl({
        src: [soundFileName],
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        volume: 0,
        fade: 0 // removes the blip
      });
    }

    function TA() {
      var optionsA = {
        reduceVolume: .7,
        ///////////////////////////
        minSamplesA: 0,
        maxSamplesA: 2,
        startMinA: 0,
        startMaxA: 9000,
        minDelayA: 3000,
        maxDelayA: 10000,
        maxVolumeA: 1,
        //
        minSamplesB: 1,
        maxSamplesB: 2,
        startMinB: 0,
        startMaxB: 5000,
        minDelayB: 3000,
        maxDelayB: 10000,
        maxVolumeB: 1,
        //
        minSamplesC: 1,
        maxSamplesC: 4,
        startMinC: 0,
        startMaxC: 45000,
        minDelayC: 3000,
        maxDelayC: 10000,
        maxVolumeC: 1,
        //
        minSamplesD: 1,
        maxSamplesD: 5,
        startMinD: 0,
        startMaxD: 45000,
        minDelayD: 3000,
        maxDelayD: 10000,
        maxVolumeD: 1,
        //
        minSamplesE: 1,
        maxSamplesE: 5,
        startMinE: 0,
        startMaxE: 45000,
        minDelayE: 1000,
        maxDelayE: 10000,
        maxVolumeE: 1,
        //
        minSamplesF: 1,
        maxSamplesF: 3,
        startMinF: 0,
        startMaxF: 45000,
        minDelayF: 1000,
        maxDelayF: 10000,
        maxVolumeF: 1,
        //
        minSamplesG: 1,
        maxSamplesG: 5,
        startMinG: 0,
        startMaxG: 45000,
        minDelayG: 2000,
        maxDelayG: 10000,
        maxVolumeG: 1,
        //
        minSamplesH: 1,
        maxSamplesH: 4,
        startMinH: 0,
        startMaxH: 45000,
        minDelayH: 3000,
        maxDelayH: 10000,
        maxVolumeH: 1,
        //
        minSamplesI: 1,
        maxSamplesI: 3,
        startMinI: 0,
        startMaxI: 45000,
        minDelayI: 2000,
        maxDelayI: 10000,
        maxVolumeI: 1,
        //
        minSamplesJ: 1,
        maxSamplesJ: 2,
        startMinJ: 0,
        startMaxJ: 45000,
        minDelayJ: 3000,
        maxDelayJ: 10000,
        maxVolumeJ: 1,
        //
        minSamplesK: 0,
        maxSamplesK: 1,
        startMinK: 0,
        startMaxK: 45000,
        minDelayK: 3000,
        maxDelayK: 10000,
        maxVolumeK: 1
      };



      localClock();

      function localClock() {
        soundTA(optionsA);
        /*
        // THIS IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO CREATE THE IF/ELSE STATEMENT THAT WILL SKIP soundTA() when TA() is called by another function, A() for example. 
        if (foo == bar) { 
            var maxVolume = 1;
            var numberOfSamples = 1;
            playThunder(numberOfSamples, maxVolume);
        }
        else {
            // do the normal thing and don't skip soundTA()
            soundTA(optionsA);
        }
        */
      }

      function soundTA() {
        console.log('TA(); blunt wood');
        (function() {
          if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointA) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinA, optionsA.startMaxA);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayA, optionsA.maxDelayA);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeA);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesA, optionsA.maxSamplesA);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointB) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinB, optionsA.startMaxB);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayB, optionsA.maxDelayB);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeB);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesB, optionsA.maxSamplesB);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointC) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinC, optionsA.startMaxC);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayC, optionsA.maxDelayC);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeC);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesC, optionsA.maxSamplesC);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointD) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinD, optionsA.startMaxD);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayD, optionsA.maxDelayD);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeD);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesD, optionsA.maxSamplesD);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointE) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinE, optionsA.startMaxE);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayE, optionsA.maxDelayE);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeE);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesE, optionsA.maxSamplesE);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointF) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinF, optionsA.startMaxF);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayF, optionsA.maxDelayF);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeF);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesF, optionsA.maxSamplesF);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointG) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinG, optionsA.startMaxG);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayG, optionsA.maxDelayG);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeG);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesG, optionsA.maxSamplesG);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointH) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinH, optionsA.startMaxH);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayH, optionsA.maxDelayH);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeH);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesH, optionsA.maxSamplesH);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointI) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinI, optionsA.startMaxI);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayI, optionsA.maxDelayI);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeI);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesI, optionsA.maxSamplesI);
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointJ) {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinJ, optionsA.startMaxJ);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayJ, optionsA.maxDelayJ);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeJ);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesJ, optionsA.maxSamplesJ);
          } else {
            var startDelay = calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinK, optionsA.startMaxK);
            var minDelay = calculateMinDelay(optionsA.minDelayK, optionsA.maxDelayK);
            var maxVolume = calculateMaxVolume(optionsA.reduceVolume, optionsA.maxVolumeK);
            var numberOfSamples = calculateNumberOfSamples(optionsA.minSamplesK, optionsA.maxSamplesK);
          }
          masterStart(startDelay, minDelay, maxVolume, numberOfSamples);
        })();

        function masterStart(startDelay, minDelay, maxVolume, numberOfSamples) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
            if (elapsedTime > minDelay) {
              if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointJ) {
                localClock();
              }
              playThunder(numberOfSamples, maxVolume);
              elapsedTime = Date.now() - Date.now(); // define when requiring wait between sample plays
              startTime = Date.now();
            } else { // keep triggering the master clock until the wait time has passed
              setTimeout(function() {
                localClock();
              }, 500);
            }
          }, startDelay);
        }
      }

      function getSoundB(soundFileName, maxVolume, reduceVolume, loop) { // confirmed: these are the 3 arguments from getSound
        var volume = calculateReduceVolume(reduceVolume, maxVolume);
        console.log('maxVolume: ' + maxVolume)
        console.log('volume: ' + volume)
        return new Howl({
          src: [soundFileName],
          autoplay: false,
          loop: loop,
          volume: volume,
          fade: 0
          //pan: 1
        });
      }

      function playThunder(numberOfSoundsToPlay, maxVolume) {
        var potentialThunderSounds = [ // blunt wood hits
          getSoundB('audio/35.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/36.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/37.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/38.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/39.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/40.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/41.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/42.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/43.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/44.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/45.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/46.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/47.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/48.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/50.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/51.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/52.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/53.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/54.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/55.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/56.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/57.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/58.wav', maxVolume, 0, false),
          getSoundB('audio/59.wav', maxVolume, 0, false)
        ];
        var soundSequence = [];
        //Randomly pick sounds from the potential sounds and add them to the list
        for (var x = 0; x < numberOfSoundsToPlay; x++) {
          var soundIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * (potentialThunderSounds.length - 1));
          soundSequence.push(potentialThunderSounds[soundIndex]);
        }

        playSoundIfThereIsOne();

        function playSoundIfThereIsOne() {
          var currentSound = soundSequence[0];
          currentSound.play();
          soundSequence.shift();
          currentSound.once('end', playSoundIfThereIsOne);
        }
      }
    } // End Thunder Function
  </script>

  <script src="sharedloop.js"></script>
  <!--contains the shared functions for the main loops-->
  <script src="thunders.js"></script>

  <script src="js/howler.core.js"></script>
  <script src="js/siriwave.js"></script>
  <script src="js/player.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you try to log `x`, which is not defined, it will log `undefined`. I don't see any `TypeError` or `SyntaxError` here. Can you please clarify? Also, it definitely goes to `else` part.

Comment: You don't have to define a variable each time, you can simply call `mouse(1, 25);` It sounds like you think you have to pass in a variable of name `solo` in order to be able to read it inside `mouse`, but that's not the case. And referring to undefined variables is not a big deal, for instance you can do `if (x) console.log(x)` to only log it if it is defined.

Comment: Can you show some of your actual code? The example code you have is not that suitable to show how to improve it, mostly because functions are supposed to eliminate duplicate code, but your mouse function contains itself duplicate code.

Comment: Thanks, @Praveen, That's true, I'm not getting any other errors, just "undefined." Is it acceptable to have something undefined? It does go to the else part of the function which works as expected.

Comment: @forestkelley It's definitely alright. It's logging because you are logging. You can avoid logging of undefined like how ChrisG has given in their comments above. `:)`

Comment: Ok, great. I'll think more about @Chris G's solution.

Comment: @ChrisG I added my actual code.

Comment: Your actual code is so severely broken it adds no value here. Syntax errors, function declared without parameters but passed parameters that are not used, variables used that are never declared anywhere (`probabilityValue`,`probabilityPointA`), on and on. A working sample would be helpful.

Comment: That code can be optimized and simplified in a lot of ways. For starters, having keys like `minSamplesA`, `minSamplesB`, etc. is not a good idea; you'll want to use an array of objects here: `[{ minSamples: 0, ...}, { minSamples: 1, ...}]` If you do that, a function like `soundTA` will shrink to just five or six lines.

Answer (score 2):

May be instead put some abstract ID into `solo` variable, put value that will be used directly in "algorithm" (here just print in console).

```js
cat();

function cat() {
  var x = 50;
  mouse('cat', x);
}

dog();

function dog() {
  var x = 25;
  mouse('dog', x);
}

function mouse(solo, x) {
    console.log(x)
    console.log(solo) 
}
```

As laternative you can divide mouse function to tree separate functions - one which has common "calculations" and two which has calculations individual for dog and cat

Comment: This. It's the simplest and best solution, unless there are additional constraints that the OP hasn't told us about. But even those should probably be solved by sending more complex values, not by doing branching in `mouse`.

Comment: @Bergi are you saying that sending more complex values is a desirable strategy? Branching is bad? (I’m not totally clear what these terms mean, yet, but I’m interested)

Comment: @forestkelley It's hard to make absolute and generic recommendations in comments :-) But the actual code you've posted shows that my hunch was correct. Those `if/else` ladders are horrible! Instead, use an appropriate datastructure, like an array of objects, for your `optionsA`, and then find the right object (index) to work with by using a loop.

Comment: @Bergi it sounds like I have a little learning to do. Some of the terms you use (ladders and datastructures) I’m unfamiliar with. And I’m not quite sure how you envision this array of objects to to be structured, but I’ll do some searching. If you have a link that demonstrates these approaches I’d love to see. Thanks for the advice. I’m looking forward to a cleaner approach!

Comment: @forestkelley "Ladder" is just a slang term for a long row of `if … else if … else if …`. [Data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) (and the algorithms on them) are the most important tool for programming, you definitely should learn about them. I mean using an array `[{startMin: 0, startMax: 8000, …}, {startMin:0, startMax: 30000, …}, …]` instead of those enumerated "groups" of properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a default value.

e.g.

```
mouse();

function mouse(solo=false, x=false) {

  if (solo == 1) {
    console.log(x)
    console.log('cat')
  } else {
    console.log(x)
    console.log('dog')
  }
}
```

then you can check it and the variables are automatically defined, also if not set as parameter

additionally on older browser you can do it also this way:

```
function mouse(solo, x) {

  if(solo === undefined) {
    solo = false;
  }
  if(x === undefined) {
    x = false;
  }

  if (solo == 1) {
    console.log(x)
    console.log('cat')
  } else {
    console.log(x)
    console.log('dog')
  }
}
```

Comment: then press F12, ctrl +c and ctrl +v and try it

Comment: Well, I am not that dumb, else I won't be committing to Chromium project. 

Comment: well I agree your edit that I also dont know if this works on all browser. But it does at least on current  chrome and firefox.

Comment: Yep. That's right. I am aware about it. Anyway, thanks mate. 

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things by using *currying* as in the following code:

```js
const animal = (pet) => (solo,x) => console.log(pet, x, solo);

animal('dog')(25,1);
animal('cat')(50,2);
```

The animal function takes the animal 'name' and passes that along to an anonymous function that takes the *solo* and *x* parameters that also get passed into the terminal operation - in this case logging to console. Since *mouse* is called in every case in your example and only carries out the logging operation, it is curried here as the terminal operation.

Note the lack of need for the if/else construct in this case.

Comment: I’m intrigued by this answer but don’t understand currying enough, yet, to know if it will serve my needs. I’ll take some time to think it through and report back.

Comment: as you get questions, ask. I'll be happy to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need if else when you are doing the same thing in every branch of that decision tree. If you parameterise the output you can do something like this with the help of partial application:

```
const mouse = (x, output) => () => {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(output);
}
const dog = mouse(25, "dog")();
const cat = mouse(50, "cat")();
```

Comment: In my actual code each branch does a different thing.